# Absolute value Algebra 1 for Dummies

Tags: arithmetic, absolute-value

$(+a)+(-b)=+(|a|-|b|)$ if the positive $a$ is farther from zero

$(+a)+(-b)=-(|b|-|a|)$ if negative $b$ is further from zero

$(+20)+(-12)=+8 = (|20|-|12|) =+8$:

it's that? = ( +a)+(-b)=+([a]-[b]) if the positive a is further away from zero

$(+20)+(-32)=-12= -(|32|-|20|)=-12$ :

is this the one? $(+a)+(-b)= -(|b|-|a|)$ if negative $b$ is farther from zero.

$-(|b|-|a|)$, just change the sign of $32? = -12$, is that correct?

$-(|b|-|a|)$, Why is the minus sign outside the parentheses?
$+(|a|-|b|)$, why is the plus sign outside the parentheses?

Comment: Please add mathjax.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)